# How to get title tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html in string form.

```
var html = "
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Some Text
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      My First Heading
    </h1>
    <p>
      My first paragraph.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
";
```

It has title tag inside it.
How can I get the text inside title tag using jquery or javascript?

Comment: `alert(document.title);`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid as `title` should be in the `head`, not the `body`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that will get the title of the document being viewed, not the `title` element within the string.

Comment: Appears no one is reading the last line in the question

Comment: `alert(html.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1]);` at the risk of ponies.

Comment: It's just an example...I just corrected the html..

Comment: Seems like the question is more about extracting a string from within a string than about getting the title of some html document.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just try with:

```
var title = $(html).filter('title').text();
```

Comment: Sorry.. my mistake. I was thinking of another html.

Comment: ``html`` is as ``document``??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It's a variable defined by OP (in his question).

Comment: but if on a page i want to get title tag, how i can get?

Comment: For example with: `$('head title').text()`

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('title')

Comment: if I am not crazy and there are not more than 1 head and 1 title, then why not `jQuery("head title");`

Answer (score 7):

Just because no one mentioned it so far, you could also use `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()` for that purpose.

```
var domstr = "<html><head><title>Some Text</title></head><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
    doc    = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('1337');
    doc.documentElement.innerHTML = domstr;

alert( doc.title );
```

Comment: No need of doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('1337');

Answer (score 5):

This is my crack at it. Create a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) add an element to it and use `querySelector` to get the element and then `textContent` to get the text.

```
var html = "<html><head><title>Some Text</title></head><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>",
    docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    el = document.createElement('html');

el.innerHTML = html;
docFrag.appendChild(el);

var text = docFrag.querySelector('title').textContent;
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wb7A3/)**

Comment: +1 Just note that the compatibility is limited : IE7 isn't at the party

Comment: @dystroy good point, but to fix that they could always use `getElementsByTagName('title')` to get the element I suppose.

Comment: I'm putting this on all my production sites ASAP. Thank you @Loktar! Everyone use this solution

Comment: @Jhawins hahah whatever

Answer (score 4):

How about using the [DOMparser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```
var html  = "<html><head><title>Some Text</title></head><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>",
    doc   = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    title = doc.title;
```

**Note:** This is not supported on any version of Safari

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wb7A3/1/)

Comment: nice +1 have never used `DomParser` personally.

Comment: Nice +1 but only from IE10 *EDIT : and no Safari*

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, simply

```
document.title
```

For sample code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.title;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/)[1]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not preferred if you can use jQuery, but for pure Javascript:

```
/<title>(.*)<\/title>/.exec(html)[1]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Yeah, we get it -- pasting that link once per question is probably enough. I even stated that the jQuery answer is preferred, I was just trying to provide a pure Javascript alternative.  Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: @Ach your answer isn't "acceptible" it isn't even functional for other cases of parsing HTML. The question here is how to extract data from an HTML string based on tags. Your answer works in this one specific case, but is worthless and guarantees problems. Your answer should be deleted. Downvote is from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
html.substring(html.indexOf('<title>')+7, html.indexOf('</title>'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that text by using this jQuery selector.

```
$(function(){
var html = "<html><head><title>Some Text</title></head><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
var titleHTML = $(html).find("title").html();
alert(titleHTML);
});
```

It will alert "Some Text"

Comment: -1 This will return the title of the current document. It's just like `document.title`.

Comment: You don't get it : your code doesn't extract the title from the given html string.

Comment: yes, now it will work, but now that's the same answer than already made (with useless additions).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
$('head > title').text();
```